# Save user details after phone verification

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have phone verification in my project. It sends otp to users and they need to verify. When otp is sent and verified it should save user data in the DB. But I am saving before verifying their phones and I do not know how to do it. Can anybody help please?

here is my code

**views.py**

```
class RegisterApi(views.APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        phone_number = request.data.get('phone', False)
        first_name = request.data.get('first_name', False)
        last_name = request.data.get('last_name', False)
        password = request.data.get('password', False)

        if phone_number and first_name and last_name and password:
            phone = str(phone_number)
            user = User.objects.filter(phone__iexact=phone)
            if user.exists():
                return Response({
                    'status': 'Fail',
                    'detail': 'Phone number is already existed'
                })
            else:
                key = send_otp(phone)
                if key:
                    old = OTPModel.objects.filter(phone__iexact=phone)
                    if old.exists():
                        old = old.first()
                        count = old.count
                        if count > 5:
                            return Response({
                                'status': 'Fail',
                                'detail': 'Limit Exceeded'
                            })

                        old.count = count + 1
                        old.save()
                        return Response({
                            'status': 'True',
                            'detail': 'OTP resent',
                            'response': response
                        })


                    else:
                        OTPModel.objects.create(
                            phone=phone,
                            otp=key
                        )


                        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
                        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
                        serializer.save()
                        return Response({
                            'status': 'True',
                            'detail': 'OTP sent successfully',
                            'account': serializer.data
                        })

                else:
                    return Response({
                        'status': 'Fail',
                        'detail': 'Error in sending otp'
                    })

        else:
            return Response({
                'status': False,
                'detail': 'Phone number is not entered'
            })
```

To validate otp this code is used.

```
class ValidateOTP(views.APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        phone = request.data.get('phone', False)
        otp_sent = request.data.get('otp', False)

        if phone and otp_sent:
            old = OTPModel.objects.filter(phone__iexact=phone)
            if old.exists():
                old = old.first()
                otp = old.otp

                if str(otp_sent) == str(otp):
                    old.verified = True
                    old.save()
                    return Response({
                        'status': 'True',
                        'detail': 'OTP verified successfully'
                    })
                else:
                    return Response({
                        'status': 'False',
                        'detail': 'OTP is incorrect'
                    })
```

everything works fine but it saves user details before verification. I need to save after verification. How can I solve this issue? Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

You're returning as soon as you go through your if statement. Maybe do:

```
if condition:

    store details
    return
```

rather than:

```
if condition:

    return
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Before you suggested I've already done that)) It did not work